# fetching data with axios and rendering flatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, react-native-flatlist

I've been trying out Axios with react native, but I'm having trouble. The flatList doesn't render the data and gives me a warning 'warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.'

I have been looking online for a few hours now and can't find a solution. The closest thing I could find is setting up the keyExtractor, which I did.

here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Axios from 'axios';

export default App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
      .then(({data}) => setData({data}))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  });

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <FlatList
          data={JSON.stringify(data)}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

I understand it's probably a very simple problem, but I would be very thankful if you helped me.

I think it's worth mentioning that it works with fetch. So I think the problem is with the axios.get request and not the flatList.

here is the API if its any use:

```
{
  "title": "The Basics - Networking",
  "description": "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
  "movies": [
    { "id": "1", "title": "Star Wars", "releaseYear": "1977" },
    { "id": "2", "title": "Back to the Future", "releaseYear": "1985" },
    { "id": "3", "title": "The Matrix", "releaseYear": "1999" },
    { "id": "4", "title": "Inception", "releaseYear": "2010" },
    { "id": "5", "title": "Interstellar", "releaseYear": "2014" }
  ]
}
```

edit: After trying out the answers here it stopped giving a warning, but it renders an empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need log data to debug.
First: `setData({data})` is wrong.
Second: don't use `JSON.stringify(data)`.
Third: `keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}` is wrong

Try this code below

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Axios from 'axios';

export default App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log("defaultApp -> data", data.movies)
        setData(data.movies)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator /> : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            // console.log("index", index)
            return index.toString();
          }}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            console.log("item", item)
            return (
              <Text style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>
            )
          }}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In render items, you need to provide a key to the text:

```
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Text key={item.title}>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>
      )}
```

It would be like this, assuming that item.title is unique.

To provide more context on why this is an issue is that react uses keys to identify which items in a list are the same between renders so it can do less work than creating whole new items on each render. Essentially, React uses keys to determine what elements are the same element. So if you change a key between each render, react will assume that element is a new one and unmount the old before mounting the new.

It is possible to use an index as the key, but that's less performant than using a unique identifier. As using an index means that if you sort or otherwise re-order the list, it will have to do a lot more work to reconcile the differences than just moving the dom nodes around.

Edit:
I've fixed the other problems you were having aside from the initial question.

The `useEffect` call needed to use a dependency array so it wasn't being called every re-rendered.

The data from the axios call needed to use data.movies in order to get the movies array.

The data being passed into the FlatList needed to not be stringified as that was causing it render every stringified character as a new row (the commas).

https://snack.expo.io/rVzXb!gsJ

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm really grateful for providing context. Although it still doesn't fix my issue completely. I am not getting the warning anymore, but It is only rendering an empty list

Comment: @luciferm105 I've fixed the issues, so take a look at the snack link I added.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        FlatList
          data={JSON.stringify(data)}
          keyExtractor={(id, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>
          )}
        />
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! it stopped giving me a warning, but it still renders an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

```
keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id.toString()}
```

The key initially comes in as a number and you must convert it to a string.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [answer]. Code-only answers might not be very helpful to OP or future viewers of this answer. Good answers include some explanation of _why_ this answer works and _what the OP got wrong_